# Database First Migration and Foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I tried to do Db first migration. But my table with foreign key not inserted in to the table and not throwing error as well. Here is my code.

My master table

```
public partial class A
{        
    public A()
    {
        this.B = new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string AID { get; set; }        

    
    public virtual ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
}
```

And my child table.

```
 public partial class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string AID { get; set; }        

    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

And my repository

```
    private ARepository _aRepository;

    private BRepository _bRepository;

    public ARepository ARepository => _aRepository ?? (_aRepository = new ARepository(Context));

    public BRepository BRepository => _bRepository ?? (_bRepository = new BRepository(Context));
```

While trying to insert data to child table I did not get any error and also my child table not get inserted.

```
private void AddB(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var a = unitOfWork.ARepository.Get(x => x.AID == id)?.FirstOrDefault(); // I am getting the user values here
            var b = new B()
            {
                //A = a, I tried this as well
                AID = a.AID,   
            };

            unitOfWork.BRepository.Add(b);
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            unitOfWork.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }
```

I don't know what preventing the insert operation. Help me to get rid of these.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, could you please copy paste the stacktrace ?

Comment: I did not get any exception.

Comment: @AlexSpitz You are right.I got some exception in saveChanges() method which I unaware of.Now I am able to fix the issue by adding primary key to the child table. Thank you